# Multiple relations of the same instance - Django

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys

Let's say I have a model that acts as a list

```
class ListModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254)
```

and a model which will populate the list

```
class Model(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    list = models.ManyToManyField(ListModel, related_name='model')
```

How can I have one instance of Model in my ListModel multiple times.

Is there a way to have a single instance related multiple times? Could I have some kind of 'count' for each instance of Model?

Edit: Should have been ManyToManyField, not ForeignKey. Still the same question of the same instance of Model being related multiple times to ListModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ManyToMany](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) field instead of a ForeignKey.

```
class Model(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    lists = models.ManyToManyField(ListModel, related_name="models")
```

This way a Model can relate to multiple ModelLists and a ModelList can be related to multiple Models.

```
model1.lists
model_list1.models
```